# i want to get the FCM token

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
I/FirebaseApp(15825): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
D/eglCodecCommon(15825): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
D/EGL_emulation(15825): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf24530e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebb67470)
D/eglCodecCommon(15825): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
D/SharedPreferencesImpl(15825): Time required to fsync /data/user/0/com.example.finalsafehub/shared_prefs/FirebaseHeartBeatW0RFRkFVTFRd+MTo3OTk3MTA4NTY2MDg6YW5kcm9pZDo1NGU5MjU2OWNjOWZiMTIwOGYxMGM1.xml: [<1: 0, <2: 0, <4: 0, <8: 0, <16: 0, <32: 0, <64: 0, <128: 0, <256: 0, <512: 0, <1024: 0, <2048: 0, <4096: 1, <8192: 0, <16384: 0, >=16384: 0]
D/SharedPreferencesImpl(15825): Time required to fsync /data/user/0/com.example.finalsafehub/shared_prefs/FirebaseHeartBeatW0RFRkFVTFRd+MTo3OTk3MTA4NTY2MDg6YW5kcm9pZDo1NGU5MjU2OWNjOWZiMTIwOGYxMGM1.xml: [<1: 0, <2: 0, <4: 0, <8: 0, <16: 0, <32: 0, <64: 0, <128: 0, <256: 0, <512: 0, <1024: 0, <2048: 0, <4096: 1, <8192: 1, <16384: 0, >=16384: 0]
W/FirebaseInstanceId(15825): Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval
D/SharedPreferencesImpl(15825): Time required to fsync /data/user/0/com.example.finalsafehub/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.appid.xml: [<1: 0, <2: 0, <4: 0, <8: 0, <16: 0, <32: 0, <64: 0, <128: 0, <256: 0, <512: 0, <1024: 0, <2048: 1, <4096: 0, <8192: 0, <16384: 0, >=16384: 0]
```

this is my error .. any solution?

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Notification',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Test> createState() => TestState();
}

class TestState extends State<Test> {
  getToken()async{
   String? mytoken= await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
   print("============================================");
   print(mytoken);
  }
@override
void initState(){
getToken();
  super.initState();
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Notification'),
      ), // AppBar
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
my code
```

Comment: If you're using physical device then Restart your phone and if you're using emulator then enable the cold boot option from the emulator settings.

And still you face the issue then share your firebase configuration.